# StackExchange.Redis IDatabase.SetScan() is not returning cursor

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

Here is my code

```
 ConnectionMultiplexer plex;
 plex = redisConnectionProvider.GetMultiplexer();
 var db = plex.GetDatabase();
 var values = db.SetScan(key);
```

I thought return values of SetScan will be an IEnumerable<> where the first element is a cursor and second element is a set of values from the Redis Set. But the result contains only set members- no cursor value. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetScan` actually returns an `IEnumerable<RedisValue>`.

The cursor will be internally handled by the library. Depending on your parameters and server features, it will use SMEMBERS or SSCAN.

You can operate over the resulting `IEnumerable` for example:

```
IEnumerable<RedisValue> values = db.SetScan(key, "a*");
var firstItem = values.First();
```

Will return the first matched element starting with *a*.